# Header column span in Jtable to show two columns under one header- Jtable Java swings

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable, jtableheader

I am checking for solution to show Header column span where we need to add two columns under one header . The solutions which were present are creating own Jtable component which is very complex. Can someone please help me solve this?

Below is the sample table pattern:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeqIl.png]